# Created new branch by mistake and need to get to previous branch

Tags: git

I am relatively new to git and github. I made some changes on my master branch, and instead of doing "git add ." with my master branch and going through the process to push these changes, I did 'git checkout -b xyz'.

I am now on a new branch xyz but need to get to the master branch that I haven't done "git add ." on yet, and I need to push my old branch to github. How can I go back to the master branch that I haven't pushed yet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have done is bascially creating a new branch and moving to that branch.

If you want to go back to the master branch you need to do:

```
git checkout master
```

And since you don't need the `xyz` branch anymore you could also delete it:

```
git branch -D xyz
```

Finally, in order to push your latest changes to the master branch of your remote (which I suppose is called `origin`) you need to do:

```
git add .

git commit -am "Your commit message"

git push origin master
```

*Edit*

Like I told you on one of my replies, I think you should take the time to read at least the first chapters of the [Pro git](http://progit.org/book/) book by Scott Chacon. It is really worth it and it will help you understand the basics of how git works.

Comment: I believe I have two masters. One with all my lastest changes that I forgot to push and the master on github without my lastest changes. Will checkout master call my master will all the changes I haven't pushed yet (that's the one I want)?

Comment: See my edit, I added the process to push your changes on the master branch of your remote (the one on github).

Comment: Cool, I also recommand you reading the `Pro git` book if you haven't done it yet. It's really worth it! http://progit.org/book/